# Why the integrity of the ESP extension header is integrity protected but not encrypted?

Tags: ipsec, network-security

[ESP header + IP datagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4M9Y.png)

As you see in the picture, part of ESP header is only authenticated but not encrypted. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

- Authentication = I am sure of the identity of the person who sent the message.
- Encryption = I can only understand the message if I have the decryption key

Here encryption is not done because that unencrypted ESP portion is used by the other terminal to construct the key with which to decrypt the rest of the message. If a message (regardless of technology) is used to distribute or construct a key then I cannot encrypt it using the same key simply because the other device would never know how to translate it. Remote key exchanges work this way, you don't encrypt your portion of the key but focus on authentication. The algorithms generally used for these purposes (and i think for example of [Diffie–Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) are designed to be robust to brute force attacks but are vulnerable to man in the middle: this is why strong authentication is required.